# Como validar input de tipo date (fecha) - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, html5, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un input del tipo date (fecha) el cual se debe completar manualmente, a la hora de guardar un registro en la vista create.blade no me permite guardar el registro, me dice "El campo fecha_hora es requerido" y en realidad lo completo pero no guarda.

Creo que es un problema con la validación de este tipo de dato.

En la function store del controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function store (CotizacionFormRequest $request)
    {

            $cotizacion=new Cotizacion;
            $cotizacion->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
            $cotizacion->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
            $cotizacion->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
            $cotizacion->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
            $cotizacion->Precio=$request->get('Precio');
            $cotizacion->Impuesto=$request->get('Impuesto');
            $cotizacion->Moneda=$request->get('Moneda');
            $cotizacion->Registro=$request->get('Registro');
            $cotizacion->Fecha_Hora=$request->date(format);
            $cotizacion->Condicion='1';
            $cotizacion->save();

            return redirect()->route('cotizaciones.edit', $cotizacion->idcotizacion)
            ->with('info', 'Cotización registrada correctamente');
    }
```

En el formulario de la vista create, tengo el siguiente campo tipo input:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fecha_hora">Fecha de Cotización</label>
                    <input name="fecha_hora" type="date" required value="{{old('fecha_hora')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de Cotización...">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y en el FormRequest tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [

        'idmedicamento'=>'required',
        'Precio'=>'required',
        'Impuesto'=>'max:20',
        'Moneda'=>'required|max:20',
        'Registro'=>'max:20',
        'Fecha_Hora'=>'required|date'

        ];
    }
```

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primera, tu input tiene un nombre diferente que el de tu validación, se debe de llamar exactamente igual.

Para validar, depende de como quieras validarla, si lo que quieres es una fecha que no sea relativa de acuerdo a la función `strtotime` de `PHP`, utiliza `date` tal y como lo tienes aquí:

```
'fecha_hora'=>'required|date'
```

Ahora si quisieras un formato en específico, debes de usar `date_format`, por ejemplo si tu fecha quieres que quede como año-mes-día_de_dos_dígitos, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
'fecha_hora'=>'required|date_format:Y-m-d'
```

Los caracteres "Ymd" significan el formato que deseas, los cuales, puedes ver la referencia [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) para ver cuales necesitas. Los caracteres "-" son solo separadores pero tu puedes ponerle también "/" o el caracter que necesites.

También es importante mencionar que si vas a validar fechas con alguna de estas dos formas, solo puedes usar una regla, es decir, solo puedes incluir ya sea `date` o `date_format` JAMÀS ambas.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el problema es que el name que le pusiste en el input de la fecha es "fecha_hora" y el nombre que le pusiste a la hora de quererlo validar es "Fecha_Hora". Debes de ponerlo ambos con la misma estructura (respetar las minúsculas y mayúsculas que pusiste en el name)