# Laravel - Obtener fecha de un bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-6

tengo un proyecto en laravel y en la plantilla blade tengo un bootstrap-datepicker.

Hago una llamada POST por AJAX para enviar los datos a un controlador, la fecha la envio en formato español tal como esta 10/05/2020

Y en el controlador me dice que la fecha no es un datetime correcto, mi pregunta es como hago para parsearlo en el validador.

Tengo este código

```
    /**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'date_measured' => 'date'
    ]);


    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    }

    return Measurements::create($input);

}
```

Con carbon si que consigo pasar la fecha del formado d/m/Y a y-m-d para insertarla en mysql, pero lo que no veo es como "ponerlo" en el validador.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como validar input de tipo date (fecha) - Laravel 5.8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286397/como-validar-input-de-tipo-date-fecha-laravel-5-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Supongamos que tienes una fecha que te llega así:

```
$fechaRecibida = "12/11/2020";
```

Como necesitamos tenerla en un formato distinto, la parseamos por medio de Carbon de esta forma:

```
$fechaFormateada =  now()::parse($fechaRecibida);
```

Si ahora imprimes la variable: `$fechaFormateada` tendrías algo así:

```
>>> $fechaFormateada;
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1602374400 {#3747
     date: 2020-10-11 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
     timezone: "UTC",
   }
```

En este punto si por ejemplo quieres usar los métodos como:

- year
- month
- day
- monthName
- toDateString

Ya lo podrás realizar pues la fecha será una instancia de Carbon a la cual le podrás aplicar todas las operaciones que esta biblioteca permite

Puedes [leer mas aquí](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)