# Validar fecha y hora laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue3

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto front con Vue3 y backend con Laravel, el problema que tengo y no logro resolver es la validacion al insertar la fecha y hora, tengo en mi tabla el campo como datetime, luego en mi formRequest tengo mi validacion como la muestro en el codigo, he probado como datetime pero no sirve.

```
"horavisita" => "required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s",
"horasalida" => "required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s",
```

y desde el front tengo mi input como

```
type="datetime-local"
```

y por lo que veo lo esta pasando asi: `2022-05-08T16:33` con una T entre la fecha y la hora.
como hago para que envie el formato correcto?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te sirve esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286397/como-validar-input-de-tipo-date-fecha-laravel-5-8)?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como validar input de tipo date (fecha) - Laravel 5.8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286397/como-validar-input-de-tipo-date-fecha-laravel-5-8)

Comment: Algo pero no es la solucion al problema completo que tengo amigo, mejor voy a actualizar mi post con todos los detalles para que se entienda bien... en unos minutos actualizo el post completo.

Comment: Creo que sí la puede responder, sólo tienes que leer el enlace a los formatos de hora y la pregunta queda respondida

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format), la validación `date_format` valida que el campo que se le pase este en el formato especificado.

Supongo que como la fecha esta en un formato diferente (lo digo por la T que tiene entre las horas y los minutos), la validación siempre fallara.

Prueba convirtiendo la fecha a `string` y envíala con el formato que requieres.

O también prueba especificando los segundos. Por lo que veo en la primera imagen, solo especificas las horas y minutos, pero no los segundos.

Comment: Hola amigo, mas menos por ahi puede ir mi solucion, pero voy a actualizar mi post completo con todos los detalles para darme a entender mejor